# Syncing events history for specific addresses, possible?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, synchronization

I am writing software that needs the full history of events but I only need it for a certain contract address, which I would guess is a very common use case for app developers.

Is there a way I can sync (with parity ideally but geth if need be) to only that specific history and so hopefully speed up the process of syncing? It takes a hours to a day to sync depending on gap in between last sync and now if you grab the full history for everything.

Thanks.